# While working on IIS System.Diagnostic.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId is generated empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

we are using System.Diagnostic.Trace.CorrelationManager class to accomplish end to end tracing.The class has a guid property "ActivityId" which is generated by default on every request.
Our tracing is working well on iis express but after deploy project on iis System.Diagnostic.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId is not generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Express will probably have a module configured which will be setting the ActivityId on the CorrelationManager. I believe a number of modules do this, one example is FailedRequestsTracingModule (you don't actually need be monitoring failed requests so may have less of a performance overhead) and many APM tools like Stackify will do the same.

If Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId is empty you could ensure IIS is configured to use a module that sets it or alternatively you can create a simple one like:

```
public class SetActivityIdModule : IHttpModule {
  public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
  context.BeginRequest += (sender, args) =>
    {
      if (Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId == Guid.Empty) Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid();
    };
  }
  public void Dispose() {}
}
```

Comment: Do you know if `ActivityId` is set by IIS when it hosts an Asp.Net Core app?

Comment: I don't now for sure, would need to test but I suspect it will depend how you are hosting your core app. I think you'll be on your own with the out-of-process hosting model but if you are using the in-process hosting model. That said Kestrel would be 'responsible' so might be set there.I think this would be as it was so the http module above would work as is. You might have already worked this out, if so would be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions i came up with enabling request tracing module on iis but that leads too much overload on server so i decided to generate it by my self instead of trusting on iis